# Is there a version of Hamilton's infinite dimensional family of implicit function theorems which gives us a submersion map?

Tags: frechet-manifold, implicit-function-theorem

Hamilton, in his [notes](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183549049) on "Inverse Function Theorem of Nash and Moser" states a theorem(1.1.3 on Page 172), where a given nonlinear map between tame Frechet spaces is locally surjective, if the derivative is surjective in an open neighbourhood(and this should be witnessed by a smooth tame family of right inverses). As is standard for tame Frechet spaces, we require a condition in a neighbourhood and not just at the point.

However, the conclusion does not give us a submersion, only that the nonlinear map is surjective. My question is can we get a submersion as a result from the same assumptions or possibly, by making the assumptions stronger?

Glockner in his [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.05795) has several foundational results but these are in the Banach and finite dimensional case.

Comment: After typing this question came across Tobias Diez's thesis where Therorems 2.2.3 and 2.2.13 seem to solve this question.